# Backup Google organisation suspended email addresses

Tags: email, backup, thunderbird, google-workspace

I'm looking for the best solution to backup multiple accounts for our company Google organisation (G Suite).

**We want to backup:**

- Drive files
- Email

**Problem:**

We met the limit for the number of accounts that we can create for our license. We have a lot of suspended accounts, we cannot delete those because by law we need to keep this kind of information for a while.

**What we tried:**

We came up with the idea of creating a special dedicated account to store the backup data of all the suspended users.

1. I a made a backup for all the users (mbox format)
2. Enabled IMAP on the dedicated account.
3. Configured the dedicated account into Thunderbird using IMAP.
4. Drag & Drop the mbox files into Thunderbird, so the emails will the synced with the dedicated account.

It turned out this approach was far from ideal because Thunderbird is struggling with the amount of data that it needs to handle. Also the syncing process turned out to be messed up. Many Conversations could not be found that should be already imported.

I also looked into the Google Migrate administrator service but unfortunately it does not suits our needs.

I am looking for a solution that meets the following requirements:

- We prefer not to upgrade our license.
- We want to delete the suspended users after backing to make room for the future new accounts.

Suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: "by law we need to keep this kind of information" then you should upgrade your licence. The law trumps everything else ...

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Yes it true, the law trumps everything else. Because of that it means we cannot just delete the accounts, but have to back it up like I trying to do now. I does not mean upgrading our license is our only option. (if there are no other options)

Answer (score 0):

You can try [CubeBackup](https://www.cubebackup.com) to backup Google Drive and Gmail data for all accounts in your company.  It is free to use for 14 days.  This solution should meet your requirements with no cost at all.